# Where between in laravel not returning the date that entered in the limit?

Tags: laravel

$tasks->whereBetween('start_datetime', [$request['start_date_report'], $request['end_date_report']]);

not returning **$request['end_date_report']** data.

Comment: What's the content of `$request`? How is `start_datetime` defined in the database?

Answer (score 0):

This problem typically not related to Laravel or any framework, the problem is in the logic of your query.

The problem is probably like this:

- You have a datetime column
- Your data include the time part, for example you have data `2017-12-01 08:00:00` and `2017-12-02 09:00:00`
- Your query does not include the time part: `between '2017-12-01' and '2017-12-02'`

This would result only one data that is `2017-12-01 08:00:00`, this is because every database engine would default the time to `00:00:00` so your query is equal to `between '2017-12-01 00:00:00' and '2017-12-02 00:00:00'`

Therefore, `2017-12-02 09:00:00` is greater than the upper limit of `2017-12-02 00:00:00`, thus not included in the result

So, if you want to include `2017-12-02 09:00:00` in the result, you can add the end date by 1 day (without the time part of-course), or make sure you compare the date part only